# How do conditional densities look like when the base measure does not factorize?

Tags: measure-theory, conditional-probability, density-function

Assume we have random variables $X,Y$ mapping from a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ to some spaces $\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y}$.

We assume there is some measure $\mu$ on the product space $\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y} $ such that there exists a radon-nikodyn derivative of the joint distribution with respect to this measure,
that is
$$ \frac{d \mathbb{P}_{(X,Y)}}{d\mu} = p(x,y).$$

Now in the case that $\mu$ factorizes we can obtain conditional densities via

$$p(x|y) = \frac{p(x,y)}{p(y)} = \frac{\frac{d \mathbb{P}_{(X,Y)}}
{d\mu}}{  \frac{d\mathbb{P}_X}   {d\mu_{\mathcal{X}}  }}.$$

I was wondering what happens in the general case, i.e. where $\mu$ does not necessarily behave like e.g. the Lebesgue-measure.
I suspect that I have to use the
[disintegration theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem) in some way, but I cannot wrap my head around this. Maybe I would need something like
$$ \frac{\frac{d \mathbb{P}_{(X,Y)}}
{d\mu}}{  \frac{d\mathbb{P}_X}   {d\mu(dx|y)  }}$$

but I can not really prove it with my basic knowlege of measure theory.

Comment: When you write *density* in measure theory, you should always keep in mind that it is a shorthand for *density with respect to ...* and you need to fix some basic measure. So which measures would you like to compute densities with respect to on $\mathcal X$ and $\mathcal Y$?

Comment: In my understanding, to mimic the lebesgue-case, I would want that $p(x|y)$ is a density w.r.t. $\mu(dx|y)$, is that correct?

Comment: what do you mean by "$\mu$ factorizes"? That there is Radon-Nikodym derivative respect to some other measure?

Comment: @Masacroso I meant this as in the case for the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, where we essentially have the product of $n$ 1-d Lebesgue measures

Comment: maybe the answer that you want is the [Radon-Nikodym theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem)